# Getting a chat app running on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, juggernaut

I have a chat app on the heroku cedar stack based on juggernaut2 = https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut and I found out that the Cedar stack is currently built around the assumption that you'll use one language/framework per app. This causes my application to not run properly, since the juggernaut server can not be started as I would do locally (1. Start rails server: rails server thin 2. Start redis server: redis-server 3. Start juggernaut: juggernaut).

The way my app currently works it has juggernaut2 and the javascript chat application all in one heroku app so therefore it doesn't work properly.

I have pushed another app that is solely juggernaut2, and one app with the chat application. I am running Redis To Go on the chat application. But my question is how do I get these two different applications to communicate with each other?

It seems like maccman got this to work with his holla app = https://github.com/maccman/holla.

Answer (score 0):

Make them both use the same Redis instance.

https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut/wiki/Heroku

Comment: How do I set the chat app to have the same Redis instance as the juggernaut app when the chat app isn't a node.js app.         heroku run node
Running node attached to terminal... up, run.11
sh: node: not found

Comment: Sounds like you don't have your node app running correctly. Juggernaut runs on node in its own app, Redis runs as a service (redistogo), and your chat app runs as a separate app. Your chat app communicates with Redis through the Juggernaut ruby library.

Comment: How do I load the localhost:8080/application.js on heroku?